# How to print a certain level directory of webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, directory, parent, html

Say I have a website:

website.com/categories/stuff/morestuff

How would i print 'stuff' if I am in 'morestuff' currently.
Meaning print the second directory or third and so on. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "print" exactly? What form do you want the result in, as a JavaScript variable?

Comment: yeah a variable would be nice. I just dont know the regular expression (if thats what it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the string document.location.href, split it at / characters, and then use the second to last string in the array

```
var a = document.location.href.split('/');
alert (a[a.length-2]);
```

Comment: how would you do it from the left by the way?

Comment: something like: alert (a[3]);

Answer (score 1):

window.location.href gives you the url in the browser so you could do something like this:

```
var arr = window.location.href.split('/')
```

Now you have all the pages in an array

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your `window.location` variable.

It contains the whole URL. You can parse out the required information from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the variables `location.pathname` and `window.location` .  I got these from [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp) and [Mozilla's Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) and highly recommend both as a source of information for beginners!